Junit test cases failing for static method with java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PASCAL_CASE_TO_CAMEL_CASE error

creating the sqs object to publish message to sqs queue.

public final class ClientFactory {

    private SqsClientFactory() {
        throw new ConstructorCallForbiddenException();
    }
    
  
    public static AmazonSQS buildSqs(String awsRegion) {
        String regionName = Optional.ofNullable(awsRegion).filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank).orElseGet(() -> {
            var region = Regions.getCurrentRegion();
            if (region != null) {
                return region.getName();
            }
            throw SqsClientException.regionNotAvailable();
        });

        return AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(regionName).build();
    }
}


This is our main class there we are sending the message to amazon sqs and method first line we are trying to set sqs mock object from UT.

@Component
@Slf4j
public class Publisher {

    public void sendMessageToSqs(String eventPayload) {
        AmazonSQS sqs = SqsClientFactory.buildSqsClient(awsRegion);
        try {
            Optional<String> eventAsJsonOpt = formatErrorEventAsJson(eventPayload);
            eventAsJsonOpt.ifPresent(eventJson -> {
                var smr = sqs.sendMessage(new SendMessageRequest()
                        .withQueueUrl(queueUrl));
                log.info("successfully published to SQS");
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Message failed to post into SQS queue : {} ", e);
        }
    }
    }


there when we tried to set static method return to mock Amazon sqs then returning the error. even we tried with static approach as well then it saying return type should be MockitoStatic.Verification not Amazon sqs

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SqsPublisherTest { 

    @Mock
    private AmazonSQS sqs;

    @InjectMocks
    private Publisher publisher;

    @Test
    public void testSQSClientBuilder() {
        try (MockedStatic<AmazonSQSClientBuilder> mockedBuilder = mockStatic(AmazonSQSClientBuilder.class)) {
            AmazonSQSClientBuilder mockBuilder = mock(AmazonSQSClientBuilder.class);
            mockedBuilder.when(AmazonSQSClientBuilder::standard).thenReturn(mockBuilder);

            when(mockBuilder.withRegion("us-east-1")).thenReturn(mockBuilder);
            when(mockBuilder.build()).thenReturn(sqs);

            when(SqsClientFactory.buildSqsClient("us-east-1")).thenReturn(sqs);

            publisher.sendMessageToSqs(Mockito.anyString());
        }   
}


maven pom dependencies for junit test cases

pom.xml

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


It is failing when call actual method by inject mock then below mock is not working when(SqsClientFactory.buildSqsClient("us-east-1")).thenReturn(sqs);

try mockStatic for SqsClientFactory as well.

Yes, i tried MockedStatic mockSqs = mockStatic(SqsClientFactory.class);
SqsClientFactory mockSqsClient = mock(SqsClientFactory.class);
mockSqs.when(SqsClientFactory.buildSqsClient("us-east-1")).thenReturn(mockSqs);   then return mock is compatible with mockSqs or sqs mock

Edit the post and include the full error stack trace. I didn't get what you meant. then return mock is compatible with mockSqs or sqs mock

mockSqs.when(SqsClientFactory.buildSqsClient("us-east-1")).thenReturn(sqs);
or
mockSqs.when(SqsClientFactory.buildSqsClient("us-east-1")).thenReturn(mockSqsClient);
Error in both case --- java: incompatible types: com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS cannot be converted to org.mockito.MockedStatic.Verification

tried with
mockSqs.when((MockedStatic.Verification) SqsClientFactory.buildSqsClient("us-east-1")).thenReturn(sqs);
even getting error org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:  AmazonSQS$MockitoMock$UvTah4Y5 cannot be returned by toString() toString() should return String 

try with lamda, mockSqs.when(() -> SqsClientFactory.buildSqs("us-east-1")).thenReturn(sqs);

Thanks for suggestion, As your suggested step sqs mock have return null value and giving below error
Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS$MockitoMock$65V1Hs7W.toString()

wait, why are you passing Mockito.anyString() as an argument when calling publisher.sendMessageToSqs()? Use actual String.

Yes we passed origin string but getting Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS$MockitoMock$65V1Hs7W.toString() error
publisher.sendMessageToSqs("individual");

Thanks it mock when pass as mockSqs.when(() -> SqsClientFactory.buildSqsClient(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(sqs);
